# Rails using old (now non-existant) RVM gem directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get a Rails app running on Ubuntu 14.04 (with Puma). I tried with RVM and ran into issues, so I am now trying rbenv.

This all seems to have worked. For example, I can see that Rails is installed;

```
crags@CRAGS-SERVER:~/crags$ which rails
/home/crags/.rbenv/shims/rails
```

However, when I execute;

```
rails c
```

or

```
bundle exec rails c
```

I get the following error;

```
crags@CRAGS-SERVER:~/crags$ bundle exec rails c
/home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
from /home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/crags/crags/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/crags/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/crags/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/crags/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

You'll notice that Rails is still trying to use the (now non-existant) RVM directory.

I removed all traces of RVM with

```
rvm implode
```

Plus I removed all .rvm directories and references to RVM in my PATH.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Ben

Comment: is rails installed on your current ruby version? What ruby version do you get when you do ``rbenv local``

Comment: Well, well, well... this is interesting! 

`crags@CRAGS-SERVER:~/crags$ rbenv local
rbenv: no local version configured for this directory`

Comment: Give `gem env` and tell me the path where the gems installed.

Comment: ``gem install rails`` may solve your problem if you don't have it installed on the current global ruby version

Answer (score 1):

Sorry everyone - false alarm. Per the request from @Paven I get this from

gem env

output

```
crags@CRAGS-SERVER:~/crags$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.1.2 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/crags/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/crags/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/crags/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/crags/.gem/specs
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
   - /home/crags/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
   - /home/crags/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
   - /home/crags/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin
   - /home/crags/.rbenv/libexec
   - /home/crags/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
   - /home/crags/.rbenv/shims
   - /home/crags/.rbenv/bin
   - /usr/local/sbin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /usr/bin
   - /sbin
   - /bin
   - /usr/games
   - /usr/local/games
```

A simple shell logout / login fixed it. I must have had some old config lying around.

Sorry about that!

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)